# Task Scheduler Cannot find remote File

Tags: windows-services, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I have an SSIS package on a server, ServerA that invokes a scheduled task on a remote server, ServerB, and it had been successfully running without incident until a recent server outtage bonked everything up. Getting things back online, the SSIS package is now failing where once it had succeeded in running the package at the step where it invokes the scheduled task. The Execute Process Task that had been working is below:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe" /run /s ServerB /tn "TaskName"
```

I was able to manually run the task via the Scheduler service on ServerB. When trying to call the same task via the command line in ServerA the below error was returned:

ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.

The mapped network drives are all accessible and don't seem to have any issues, but I'm one step separated from the actual network configurations in our environment. Any troubleshooting advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This error appears if the firewall rule "Remote Scheduled Tasks Management" blocks the access.

Also when the firewall blocks the access, the querying of all tasks does not print anything:

```
schtasks /query /s ServerB
```

and again, querying a specific tasks returns the same error:

```
schtasks /query /s ServerB /tn "TaskName"
ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Seems that when upgrading a Windows server to newer version (at least from W2016 to W2022), the firewall rule is disabled again, and starts blocking the access.